# Inflate Rectangle by Percentage

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I know to `Inflate` the Rectangle by Pixels, How to by Percentage?

Ex:  `rect.Inflate(45%,105%)` the integer value should be passed as percent value not pixel value

How??

Comment: `rect.Inflate(rect.Width * .45, rect.Height * 1.05);` Not precise though...

Comment: yes i've got it... the simple calc.. Thank you.. @ebyrob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `SizeF` structure to allow for you to calculate the width and height values by percentage values, like this:

```
SizeF theSize = new SizeF(rect.Width * .45, rect.Height * 1.05);
```

`SizeF` holds floating point values, but unfortunately there is no overload for `Inflate()` that accepts a `SizeF`, but it does have an overload that accepts a `Size` structure. So we need to convert a `SizeF` to a `Size`, like this:

```
// Round the Size
Size roundedSize = Size.Round(theSize);

// Truncate the Size
Size truncatedSize = Size.Truncate(theSize);
```

Finally, we can use our converted `Size` (either the rounded or truncated), like this:

```
rect.Inflate(roundedSize);
```

OR

```
rect.Inflate(truncatedSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to do this. You will need to calculate the pixels from the percentage and use those instead.